# Regular expression which splits string into words by white space or non-alphanumeric excluding hashtag

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split a string into an array of `["words"]`. I need to have the words split by either whitespace or non-alphanumeric character excluding hashtag or underscore. The character used to split must be it's own index in the array of wors, and number of whitespaces must be preserved.

Right now I have the following:

```
  const testString = 'This #here is a #test.';

  const words = testString.split(/((?<!#)\W)/);
```

which produces:

```
[
  'This',
  ' ',
  '',
  '#',
  'here',
  ' ',
  'is',
  ' ',
  'a',
  ' ',
  '',
  '#',
  'test',
  '.',
  ''
]
```

but what I want is:

```
[
  'This',
  ' ',
  '#here',
  ' ',
  'is',
  ' ',
  'a',
  ' ',
  '#test',
  '.'
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might split on asserting what is on the right is a non word character except `#` and `_` or assert what is on the left is a space.

```
(?=[^\w#_])|(?<= )
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8OwIkY/1)

```js
const testString = 'This #here is a #test.';
console.log(testString.split(/(?=[^\w#_])|(?<= )/g));
```

---

You could also use match instead of split for your example data, to match either an optional `#` or `_` followed by 1+ word characters, or match 1+ non word characters excluding `#` and `_`

```js
const testString = 'This #here is a #test.';
console.log(testString.match(/[#_]?\w+|[^\w#_]+/g));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tokenize the strings using a *matching* approach that looks simpler:

```js
s.match(/#?\w+|\W/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MurWcY/1).

**Details**

- `#?\w+` - an optional `#` and then 1+ word chars
- `|` - or
- `\W` - any non-word char (any char other than an ASCII letter, digit or `_`).

See the JavaScript demo below:

```js
console.log('This #here is a #test.'.match(/#?\w+|\W/g))
// => [ "This"," ","#here"," ","is"," ","a"," ","#test","." ]
```

Comment: Please let know if you need to make the pattern Unicode-aware so that it could work with Unicode strings.